# Explode a string in HIVE

Tags: python, hadoop, split, hive, user-defined-functions

I have come across an interesting problem. I have a HIVE script that calls a Python UDF, to manipulate some dates. The output from Python is 6 columns, 3 are strings and 3 are arrays.

*e.g. `print '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s' % (ID1, ID2, ID3, ARR1, ARR2, ARR3)`*

Here is a row from output of my python UDF:

```
10161   10400511433810000       (0000010161, 10400511433810001) ["0011583180","0011583180","0011583180"]        ['2004-04-16', '2004-04-16', '2004-04-16']      ['2004-09-03', '2004-09-03', '2004-09-03']
```

#
PROBLEM 1:
I am using `%s` because I am unable to find a way to return arrays to HIVE in a manner that HIVE will read them as arrays.

So I created a table in HIVE that imports even the arrays as strings assuming that I will be able to split the string to an array. Script I used:

```
insert overwrite table table2
SELECT 
ID1,
ID2,
ID3,
SPLIT(ARR1, '\\\t') as ARR1,
SPLIT(ARR2, '\\\t') as ARR2,
SPLIT(ARR3, '\\\t') as ARR3
FROM table1 
LIMIT 10;
```

#
PROBLEM2: I get the following output:

```
0000010167      10400514362740001       (0000010167, 10400514362740001) ["[\"0022136941\",\"0022315161\"]"]     ["['1900-01-01', '2007-05-01']"]        ["['1900-01-01', '2008-06-16']"]
```

What I actually need is:

```
0000010167      10400514362740001       (0000010167, 10400514362740001)      0022136941       1900-01-01      1900-01-01
0000010167      10400514362740001       (0000010167, 10400514362740001)      0022315161       2007-05-01      2008-06-16
```

Answer (score 0):

In my idea, you got a horizontal table, but what you need is a vertical table. I don't know 
how to use Hive to solve this, so I solved it with mapreduce.
Yes, it's very easy with mapreduce in this situation.
This is a example in Chinese, but you just need to understand the Java code.
[mapreduce example](http://blog.csdn.net/laozhaokun/article/details/38794283).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [Exhibit](https://github.com/jwills/exhibit), a prototype of Hive UDFs/UDTFs that execute nested SQL queries within rows, and associate that with [Lateral view](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView).